# Saving Message to Hard Drive with Outlook subfolder name in filename

Tags: vba, outlook

I file my Outlook emails into *subfolders*. I would like to archive them by saving them to my hard drive.

I found code which is saving the message name as date and time, plus sender, plus subject.

I would like to add the *subfolder* name in the file name when it is saved.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim sSender As String
    Dim sCategory As String
                  
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
  
    For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
            Set oMail = objItem

            sName = oMail.Subject
            ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

            sSender = oMail.SenderName

            sCategory = oMail.Categories
     
            dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
            sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyy-mm-dd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
              vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "--hhnn", _
              vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & " -- " & sCategory & _
              " -- " & sSender & " -- " & sName & ".msg"

            sPath = enviro & "\Documents\Emails\"
            Debug.Print sPath & sName
            oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is nice example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41782997/4539709

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a Outlook MailItem, you can get the folder name by doing

`FolderName = oMail.Parent.Name`

This works as the `Folder` object is the parent of a MailItem in the Outlook Object model.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add **`oMail.Parent.Name`** to the following line

```
vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & " -- " & sCategory & " -- " & sSender & " -- " & sName & ".msg"
```

*Example*

```
vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & " -- " & sCategory & " -- " & sSender & " -- " & sName & " -- " & oMail.Parent.Name & ".msg"
```

***[See Folder.Name Property (Outlook) MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Folder.Name)***